# Looping through an array and setting variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/umHzl?editors=101

You notice that you can click a box and unclick it. What I would like is that when a certain button is clicked all other buttons are unclicked(turn back to normal color).

My attempt at this:

```
        for (var i =0; i < booths.length; i++){
                var obj = booths[i]
                obj.e1['fill'] = obj['color'];
                obj.e1['checked'] = 'false';
                $("#"+obj.name).remove();
            }
```

I know that the color is in the e1/rectangle object of the box, but I do not know how to change/access that variable. It says `obj.e1` is undefined. If I do `obj['fill']` it still doesn't work.

How would I change the colors from such a loop (or something similar).

Comment: You have an array of objects, not JSON. None of the objects has a `e1` property, so what exactly did you expect `obj.e1` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `e1`, it's `el` (lowercase 'L'). And you'll still want to use the `attr()` function, e.g.:

```
for (var i =0; i < booths.length; i++){
  var obj = booths[i]
  obj.el.attr('fill', obj['color']);
  obj.el.attr('checked', 'false');
  $("#"+obj.name).remove();
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/yFwCq