# Dplyr and Tidyverse => conditional replace all variables (looping through a dataset)

Tags: r, loops, replace, dplyr, tidyverse

This is a simple question, but the answer is taking me more time than it should. The closest answer I found was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421022/looping-through-an-array-and-setting-variables).  So, I'm here -- as always -- to ask for help!

Let's say I have a dataset with 6 variables (y1-y6) and I need to replace all values before the floor with "NA" and all values after the ceiling with "NA" as well.

So, this data
[image: Original dataset]

Will be with like the following one:

[image: new dataset]

To make my question clear, I'll need to mark the entry as `NA` if the *variable* is outside the floor and the ceiling. In other words, in the *second* row of the following image, **y1** must be replaced by `NA` (because the floor is y2) and **y6** also must be replaced by `NA`, because the ceiling is y5.

I'm a dplyr user and I'll be happy if the answer uses tidyverse environment.

Thanks much as always!

```
ds <- data.frame(floor = c(1:2),
                 ceiling = c(4,5),
                 y1 = c(1,2),
                 y2 = c(1,2),
                 y3 = c(1,2),
                 y4 = c(1,2),
                 y5 = c(1,2),
                 y6 = rep(c(1,2),3))
```

Comment: Are you looking to mark the entry as `NA` if the *value* is outside the floor/ceiling or if the *column index* is outside the floor/ceiling? Specifically, if column `y3` has value `1` with a row-floor of `2`, should that value be marked NA? In the reverse, if column `y1` has value `3` with a row-floor of `2`, should that value be marked NA?

Comment: good question! I'm trying to mark the entry as `NA` if the *variable* is not / is outside the floor and the ceiling. In other words, in the *second* row, y1 must be replaced by `NA` (because the floor is y2) and y6 also must be replaced by `NA`, because the ceiling is y5. I'll edit the question to make it clear. @MarkPeterson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by making a function that determines if the passed index is inside a set of bounds, assigning `NA` if it is or assigning a separate passed value if it is not. Here, `x` is the column index, `val` is the value you want to assign if not `NA`, `low` is the lower bound (floor), and `high` is the upper bound (ceiling):

```
altMask <- function(x, val, low, high){
  sapply(1:length(x), function(idx){
    ifelse(between(x[idx], low[idx], high[idx]), val[idx], NA)
  })
}
```

Then, you can convert your data to long format (taking care to add a row index variable to use when converting back to wide format), apply the function, and convert back:

```
ds %>%
  mutate(rowIdx = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(col, value, starts_with("y")) %>%
  mutate(value = altMask(parse_number(col), value, floor, ceiling)) %>%
  spread(col, value) %>%
  arrange(rowIdx) %>%
  select(-rowIdx)
```

Returns:

```
  floor ceiling y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
1     1       4  1  1  1  1 NA NA
2     2       5 NA  2  2  2  2 NA
3     1       4  1  1  1  1 NA NA
4     2       5 NA  2  2  2  2 NA
5     1       4  1  1  1  1 NA NA
6     2       5 NA  2  2  2  2 NA
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for the amazing solution! I'll use this today but I'll come back here to understand every step you took within this code! Your answer is really elegant!

Answer (score 0):

@Mark-Peterson's answer works well, but writing an outside function is unnecessary. 
You can just `mutate` `if_else` criteria, etc.
(`if_else` is a vectorized form of `ifelse` so the `sapply` is not needed anymore)

```r
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(floor = c(1:2),
                 ceiling = c(4,5),
                 y1 = c(1,2),
                 y2 = c(1,2),
                 y3 = c(1,2),
                 y4 = c(1,2),
                 y5 = c(1,2),
                 y6 = rep(c(1,2),3))

ds %>%
  mutate(rowIdx = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("y"), names_to = "col") %>%
  mutate(col_num = parse_number(col),
         value_after_floor_and_ceiling = if_else(col_num >= floor & col_num <= ceiling, value, NA_real_)) %>%
  select(-col_num, -value, value = value_after_floor_and_ceiling) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col") %>%
  arrange(rowIdx) %>%
  select(-rowIdx)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#>   floor ceiling    y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6
#>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1       4     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
#> 2     2       5    NA     2     2     2     2    NA
#> 3     1       4     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
#> 4     2       5    NA     2     2     2     2    NA
#> 5     1       4     1     1     1     1    NA    NA
#> 6     2       5    NA     2     2     2     2    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>